# Logon Attempt Failed WCF Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

The scenario is: I have a two desktop machines:

1. WCF Service Hosted on ABC Desktop Machine.
2. Console Application Created on CDE Desktop.

When I am trying to connect to my WCF service with the console application, I'm getting an `Logon Attempt Failed` error.

WCF Service (`web.config`)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="IISHost.Service1Behavior" name="IISHost.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IISHost.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="IISHost.IISHostBehavior" name="IISHost.IISHost">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IISHost.IIISHost">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IISHost.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="IISHost.IISHostBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Console Application (`app.config`)

```
<configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
         <bindings>
             <wsHttpBinding>
                 <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIISHost" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"  
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                     allowCookies="false">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                                 maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                                 maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                         enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message"> 
                      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                               negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"
                               establishSecurityContext="true" />
                     </security>
                 </binding>
             </wsHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
         <client>
             <endpoint address="http://yogeshpc/IISHost/IISHost.svc" 
                       binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                       bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IIISHost"  
                       contract="ServiceReference1.IIISHost"
                 name="WSHttpBinding_IIISHost">
                 <identity>
                     <dns value="localhost" />
                 </identity>
             </endpoint>
         </client>
     </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

Console Application (`.cs` file)

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new IISHostClient();
            d.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "YOGESH";
            //d.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Workgroup";
            d.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abc@123";
            d.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;
            Console.WriteLine(d.add(30, 30));
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
```

Note:UserName and Password used in the Console Application CS file is ABC Desktop machine local Username and password.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are missing some configuration for your binding on the web service:

```
  <bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name = "someNameForTheBinding">
    <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding></bindings>
```

You can check more about it [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734673.aspx)

Comment: its there in Console Application (app.config), please check above code (Console Application (app.config)) for the same.

Comment: You need to add it on the server also.